# not Understanding GlobalMaxPooling1D keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, pooling

I am not sure if I understand well the `GlobalMaxPooling1D` in `Keras`.
I have feature vector of text of uni gram & bi gram & tri and 
I concatenate them to be in form of `[ ? , 3 , 256 ]`
and then I apply `GlobalMaxPooling1D`.

So, does `GlobalMaxPooling1D` select the best feature vector and return `(batch_size, features)`?

Answer (score 2):

The GlobalMaxPooling1D layer does not select the best feature vector, but simply takes the maximum value of either feature vector from each of the 256 features.

As an example, imagine that for one sample, your three feature vectors looks like this:

```
v1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, ...]
v2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, ...]
v3 = [0, 0, 1, 0, ...]
```

After performing the GlobalMaxPooling1D operation, you would have a feature vector that looked like this, of shape (n_features):

```
v = [1, 1, 1, 0, ...]
```

When performed on a batch, this operation is performed on each sample in the batch. The size of the returned tensor will then, as you say, have a shape (batch_size, n_features).

Comment: I have posed  my problem here please check it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371157/what-is-the-kind-of-max-pooling-in-this-nlp-questionhierarchy-description)